# react native why is my textinput text in the middle?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to make a Textarea with multiline. So if I set the height of the field to 100 then the placeholder and input text is centered and not at the top.

I want it that the text begin at the top.

```
                    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 50}}>
                      <AntDesign name="infocirlceo" size={24} style={{backgroundColor: '#fff', padding: 10, borderRadius: 100, marginRight: 12}} color="#555" />
                      <TextInput
                        style={{padding: 10, height: 100, backgroundColor: '#fff', borderWidth: 1, width: 250, borderRadius: 8, borderColor: '#eee'}}
                        placeholder="Proudktbeschreibung eingeben"
                        multiline
                        numberOfLines={1}
                      />
                    </View>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried changing, and to what effect?

Comment: try `textAlignVertical: 'top'` in style

Comment: "Produktbeschreibung" just a hint u have a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think AntDesign is what's causing the issue and since you haven't shown any of the code of that component I can't tell you exactly what's wrong. But what I can show you is how you can achieve the look you are going for.

In this example I used an image inside a view instead of your AntDesign. And here is the end result (used a different image because I don't have yours)

[image: End result]

In Order to achieve that this is the code I have written

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 50 }}>

                    <View style={{ padding: 15, backgroundColor: '#fff',margin:10,borderRadius:100 }}>
                        <Image style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }} source={require("../../../../assets/icons/capture.png")} />

                    </View>

                    <TextInput
                        style={{ padding: 10, height: 100, backgroundColor: '#fff', borderWidth: 1, width: 250, borderRadius: 8, borderColor: '#eee' }}
                        placeholder="Proudktbeschreibung eingeben"
                        multiline
                        numberOfLines={1}
                    />
        </View>
```